# Is torch.as_tensor() the same as torch.from_numpy() for a numpy array on a CPU?

Tags: pytorch

On a CPU, is `torch.as_tensor(a)` the same as `torch.from_numpy(a)` for a numpy array, `a`?  If not, then why not?

From the docs for `torch.as_tensor`

> if the data is an `ndarray` of the corresponding `dtype` and
>       the `device` is the cpu, no copy will be performed.

From the docs for `torch.from_numpy`:

> The returned tensor and `ndarray` share the same memory. Modifications to
>       the tensor will be reflected in the `ndarray` and vice versa.

In both cases, any changes the resulting tensor changes the original numpy array.

```py
a = np.array([[1., 2], [3, 4]])
t1 = torch.as_tensor(a)
t2 = torch.from_numpy(a)
t1[0, 0] = 42.
print(a)
# prints [[42., 2.], [3., 4.]]
t2[1, 1] = 55.
print(a)
# prints [[42., 2.], [3., 55.]]
```

Also, in both cases, attempting to resize_ the tensor results in an error.

Answer (score 6):

They are basically the same, except than `as_tensor` is more generic:

- Contrary to `from_numpy`, it supports a wide range of datatype, including list, tuple, and native Python scalars.
- `as_tensor` supports changing dtype and device directly, which is very convenient in practice since the default dtype of Torch tensor is float32, while for Numpy array it is float64.

`as_tensor` is sharing memory with the original data if and only if the original object is a Numpy array, and the requested dtype, if any, is the same than the original data. Those are the same conditions than `from_numpy`, but are always satisfied by design for the later.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, `as_tensor` and `from_numpy` are **strictly equivalent**. From the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.as_tensor.html):

> If data is a NumPy array (an ndarray) with the same dtype and device then a tensor is constructed using torch.from_numpy().

Comment: Your answer is wrong because you confuse implication and equivalence. 
You are right to say that in certain scenarios, the two functions are the same. But `as_tensor` is more general, as @milembar answered.

Comment: Here, we're talking about a **functional equivalence** ([Similar or identical in value, meaning or effect; virtually equal.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/equivalent)), not a logic equivalence (the objects are library functions, not statements).
Even though the scope of the question (the assumption) is that the input is a numpy array, the question doesn't concern the general case. So, I still maintain that, in the context of the question posed, these functions are strictly equivalent (or interchangeable).